# Issue with running 'npm test' on windows 10

Tags: unit-testing, npm, chai, karma-mocha

I have units tests for js code. I try to run them on Windows 10 with command:

> npm test

It throws error as:

> .......\node_modules.bin\karma:2
>
> basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")
>             ^^^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>
> at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
>
> at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)